# Error with arguments in commands in Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, discord.js

so stumbled upon another issue and can't really wrap my head around it. Using the following code it keeps returning that "cannot read property "username" of undefined, however with the command "!stats @USER" the argument should have been set to the user, right?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    const args = message.content.trim().split(' ');
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

if(command === '!stats'){
  if (args.length){
  var userMentioned = args[0].id
  message.delete()
} else{
  var userMentioned = message.author.id
  message.delete()
} 

if (message.channel.id === "876597275856601168") {{
  setTimeout(function (){
    message.delete();
     const statsEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#8F00FF')
    .setAuthor(userMentioned.user.username, userMentioned.user.displayAvatarURL())
    .addFields(
        { name: '<:logoas2:876840515465797632>Current Level:', value: 'Current: **' + (userMentioned.userStats.level) + '**', inline: true },
        { name: '<:xp2:874732251571707966>Current XP:', value: 'Amount: **' + userMentioned.userStats.xp + '**', inline: true },
        { name: '<:xp3:876841199456092161>To Next Level:', value: 'Amount: **' + (userMentioned.xpToNextLevel - userMentioned.userStats.xp) + '**', inline: true },
        { name: '<:etherite:874730607106748457>Etherite:', value: 'Amount: **' + userMentioned.userStats.etherite + '**', inline: true },
        { name: '<:time:876866100774707290>Member Since:', value: 'Date: **' + userMentioned.userStats.dateofJoin + '**', inline: true },
    )
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('Avesong', client.user.displayAvatarURL());
  client.channels.cache.get("876597275856601168").send({ embeds: [statsEmbed] });
}, 500); 
}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using:

```
var userMentioned = Client.users.cache.get(args[0]);
```

Just like it's been observed before - right now you're inputting a string value which obviously does not have .id property and so on.

Why would I opt for the above? If I recall correctly - this is the most elegant way to prevent errors about the bot not being able to fetch data from users not listed in the guild. While this might not be the case, it's still wise to prevent such errors.

Also, you will probably need to check your bot's intents in the dev portal - you will most definitely need `GUILD_MEMBERS` flag active.

[Docs about cache.get()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=get)

Comment: Thanks for the help!

However the console gives me the message `Cannot read property 'displayAvatarURL of undefined` when using `var userMentioned = client.users.cache.get(args[0]);`

Comment: Try enabling GUILD_PRESENCE intent in developer portal.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting the message content does not return the user mentioned. It instead returns the string like this: `"<@UserId>"`. You can use `Message.mentions` instead.

```js
if (message.mentions.users.size){
  var userMentioned = message.mentions.users.first()
  message.delete()
}
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the error, look later he uses `userMentioned.user.username`. Remove the `.id`.

Comment: After that he should be able to use `userMentioned.username`.